# Laravel Foreign Keys with() issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Brand new to Laravel and trying to work the ORM to get data from two tables joined via a Foreign Key. I don't know what I am missing but it must be something #%#, please help and be nice :)

I have two tables `widgets` and `widget_types` were `widgets->widget_type_id` references `widget_types->id` via a foreign key. Now when using a Controller to bring in this data...only the first object has a `widget_type` parameter filled in:

**HomePageController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Widget;

class HomePageController extends Controller
{
    public function get() {
        $data['page_title'] = "Home";
        $data['widgets'] = Widget::where([ ['is_default', '=', 1], ['is_guest', '=', 1] ])->with('widget_type')->get();

        return $data['widgets'];
        return view('home', $data);
    }
}
```

Now that first return statement returns something like this:

> [{"id":1,"widget_type_id":1,"is_default":1,"is_guest":1,"widget_title":"Welcome
>   to the App","widget_content":"What good is a reward if you ain't
>   around to use it? Besides, attacking that battle station ain't my idea
>   of courage. It's more like\u2026suicide. But with the blast shield
>   down, I can't even see! How am I supposed to
>   fight?","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"widget_type":{"id":1,"class_name":"text-widget","template_name":"text_widget","friendly_name":"Text
>   Widget","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}},{"id":2,"widget_type_id":1,"is_default":1,"is_guest":1,"widget_title":"What
>   can I do here?","widget_content":"Still, she's got a lot of spirit. I
>   don't know, what do you think? Kid, I've flown from one side of this
>   galaxy to the other. I've seen a lot of strange stuff, but I've never
>   seen anything to make me believe there's one all-powerful Force
>   controlling everything. There's no mystical energy field that controls
>   my destiny. It's all a lot of simple tricks and
>   nonsense.","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"widget_type":null}]

Notice the 2nd item has `null` as a widget type

WHYYYY? I can confirm the tables are created correctly and I don't think I have the key flow reversed...(if I do...I'm sorry)

**Widget.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Widget extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'widgets';

    public function widget_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\WidgetType', 'id');
    }
}
```

**WidgetType.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class WidgetType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'widget_types';
}
```

**WidgetType Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateWidgetTypesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('widget_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('class_name');
            $table->string('template_name');
            $table->string('friendly_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('widget_types');
    }
}
```

**Widget Migration:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateWidgetsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('widgets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('widget_type_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('widget_type_id')->references('id')->on('widget_types');
            $table->boolean('is_default');
            $table->boolean('is_guest');
            $table->string('widget_title');
            $table->longText('widget_content');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('widgets');
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an incorrect eloquent relationship set up. Change your code in Widget.php `public function widget_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\WidgetType', 'widget_type_id' , 'id');
    }`

Comment: @RutvijKothari totally read the documentation wrong then...THANK YOU. If you want to add this as an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: No worries. Glad it helps. :) Happy Coding. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify the foreign key column

**Widget.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Widget extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'widgets';

    public function widget_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\WidgetType', 'widget_type_id');
    }
}
```

**WidgetType.php**

```
  <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class WidgetType extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'widget_types';

        public function widgets(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\models\Widget','widget_type_id')    
        }    
    }
```

Then in your controller you can access it.
**HomePageController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Widget;

class HomePageController extends Controller
{
    public function get() {
        $data['page_title'] = "Home";
        $data['widgets'] = Widget::where([ ['is_default', '=', 1], 
        ['is_guest', '=', 1] ])->widget_type;
        dd($data['widgets']);
       // this is belongs to method 

        return $data['widgets'];
        return view('home', $data);
    }
}
```

please let me know if you get right